# How to read a timer's value once stopped?

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, button

I've downloaded the Timer1 library but unfortunately it seems that the read() method has been removed from it. I tried also SimpleTimer library from the arduino website but the program didn't compile because of undefined reference to `SimpleTimer::SimpleTimer()' error. Anybody knows how to solve this error or just another timer library which has a read function?

To be more specific I need to start a timer as I press a button and to stop it as it is released.

Comment: Have you considered looking for an input capture library instead?

Comment: To start a timer, give it a clock by setting the CSn2..0 bits. One set of those bits stops the clock thus the timer. Read the data sheet to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here, below is a code which is you looking for. When you pressed a button then a timer is started and when you released it then a timer is stopped. And you can also see that time also means how long button is pressed.

```
const uint8_t button_pin = 2;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(button_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    static int last_button_state = HIGH;
    static unsigned int push_count;
    static unsigned long last_press_time;
    int button_state = digitalRead(button_pin);
    unsigned long now = millis();

    // Record when the button is pressed.
    if (last_button_state == HIGH && button_state == LOW) {
        push_count++;
        last_press_time = now;
    }

    // Report when the button is released.
    if (last_button_state == LOW && button_state == HIGH) {
        unsigned long push_duration = now - last_press_time;
        if (push_duration < 10) {  // discard bounce
            push_count--;
        }
        else {
            Serial.print(F("pushes: "));
            Serial.print(push_count);
            Serial.print(F(", duration: "));
            Serial.print(push_duration);
            Serial.println(F(" ms"));
        }
    }

    last_button_state = button_state;
}
```